# Detach many pages from a Dreamweaver template

Tags: dreamweaver, dreamweaver-templates

I've got a site of about 500 pages from a client, all attached to a template. Is there any way I can do a "bulk detach" rather than going through each file individually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you're working within Dreamweaver. If you have the site that is based upon a template displayed within the Files panel in Dreamweaver, go to:
Modify > Templates > Export without Markup...

You'll be asked where you want to save your files to. If you plan on doing this only once, then uncheck the two checkboxes on the UI. If you need to do it multiple times, look at the help files they may be able to let you know when you might or might not want to select those options.

If you want to stop working with the "old" file and keep working with the files within Dreamweaver, I'd export the files without markup to another folder, then change the site definition to point to the new location, or perhaps swap the contents of the folders with Dreamweaver closed (to prevent it wanting to look through everything to try to find updated links)

Note: At this time, there's a bug in Dreamweaver (I've seen it in CS3 and CS4) that was introduced by Microsoft in Vista SP2 and Windows 7, the browse for folder dialog may select a folder above the one you think you're selecting see: http://forums.adobe.com/message/2183285 ). So you'll either need to dig down one further folder, or make sure you verify/update the folder path after you've selected a folder in the browse folder.

If you're not within Dreamweaver, then you'll need to do a good bit of find and replace.

Comment: Heh, how about a bulk attach?

Comment: As templates can contain multiple editable regions (in the head as well as the body), trying to figure out what goes where in many pages and especially with pages that have differing content is just asking for trouble. Best practice is to create a new child page from your template and copy and paste into each page from the original. Not ideal, but in the end you'll be better off. Better off still may be to move to includes rather than templates, that way you can find and replace content chunks with includes/requires/whatever.

Comment: Def agreed there. Thankfully in my situation my templates were almost identical because I am new to DW templates, so after figuring out which parts I could make generic, it was a case of closing all files and search/replacing the actual DW template coded names. You might scream at me for this! But its ok, because the editable regions are identical - it was class and attribute stuff that differed in my case - phewph. 150 pages combined into 1 template not 3, woo!